Is it ok to use the kitchen baking thermostat at the air vent to measure temperature of the cool air?

I saw a mechanic on YouTube using a thermostat that almost resembles a kitchen baking thermostat. Can we use a kitchen baking thermostat to measure the temperature at the air vent? or am I mistaken, there's a specialty automotive thermostat that I need to purchase?

You can use whatever thermometer that has appropriate range. The type doesn't really matter, but may affect the accuracy.

And as far as accuracy goes, you're not looking for an exact reading ... you just need to ensure the AC is cooling where it should be and not where the hand thermometer is telling your brain where it thinks its cooling to. The only difference between a MAC branded thermometer and one you'd pull out of your kitchen is how its marked on the face.
